# Get a weeknumber from a columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following dataframe (df1):

```
        Year    Month   Day
     0  2019    10     28
     1  2019    10     28
     2  2019    10     28
     3  2019    10     28
     4  2019    10     28
```

Now, I want to create a new column in the dataframe with the weeknumber, based on the first 3 columns.

I tried:

```
    df1['Weeknumber_TillDate'] 
    =date(df1['Year'],df1['Month'],df1['Day']).isocalendar()[1]
```

This gives me the error:

```
    TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

I tried many other things, but the error is always this kind of typeError.

When I perform the code hereunder, it does work:

```
   df1 = {'Year':[2019],'Month':[10], 'Day' : [28]}

   df1['Weeknumber_TillDate'] = 
   date(df1['Year'],df1['Month'],df1['Day']).isocalendar()[1]
```

result:

```
     Year   Month   Day Weeknumber_TillDate
     2019   10       28     44
```

And I want to be able to do this for my entire dataframe (for every row).

But I'm getting my Year, Month, Day from another dataframe(df2).

So I do:

```
     df1 = {'Year':df2.iloc[:,6],'Month':df2.iloc[:,7], 'Day' : 
     df2.iloc[:,8]}
```

This gives me df1 and the dtypes are:

```
      YearSub                   int64
      MonthSub                  int64
      DaySub                    int64
```

and when I do:

```
     df1 = {'Year':[2019],'Month':[10], 'Day' : [28]}
```

2019, 10 and 28 are also int64.

So, i don't know why it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following 1 liner:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({"Year": [2019, 2018, 2017, 2017], "Month": [1, 2, 3, 12], "Day": [1, 2, 3, 30]})

df["New"] = df.apply(lambda row:  datetime.datetime(row["Year"], row["Month"], row["Day"]).isocalendar()[1], axis=1)

print(df)
```

Hope it helped to solve the issue, if any questions - feel free to ask.

Comment: that worked! Thank you! Any clarification on why this worked?

Comment: @Steven31415 this is pandas api, you can give value frrom chosen rows and then pandas do some magic, probably they have for loop inside. But you need to use apply method to gain it. Actually the presence of apply is the main difference in my code in comparison with yours.

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating over the entire dataframe using df.iterrows()!

```
df1 = df1.assign(Weeknumber_TillDate = "")
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
   row['Weeknumber_TillDate'] = date(df1['Year'].astype('int64'),df1['Month'].astype('int64'),df1['Day'].astype('int64')).isocalendar()[1].astype('int64')
```

Edit: Considering your typeError you should likely have to cast your input data to int first.

Comment: Can you try again after the edit with .astype(int)?

Comment: didn't work in my case. The suggestion of Artiom worked. But thanks for the effort!!